# Poles of filter transfer function, fifth order equation

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, polynomials

I am just trying to find the roots of the fifth-order equation. But I could get enough result from Wolfram.

Could anyone help to me about this issue?

```
FullSimplify[Solve[1+L/R s+4 k L  s^2+(3 k L^2 s^3)/R+2 k^2 L^2  s^4+(k^2 L^3 s^5)/R==0,{s}]]
```

[image]

Comment: As stated in the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem), there is no general algebraic solutions to polynomials of degree five and higher so there is nothing you (or Mathematica) can do, unless your polynomial has some special structure (for example, use `Reduce` and you will get a special case of $k=0 \implies s=-R/L$).

Comment: Is there any function to group the equation?

Comment: @analog_designer What do you mean by "group the equation"? Is [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html) perhaps what you seek?

Comment: @Roman no it is not related to my question. I just want to say parenthesize of the equation, like (1+x)(1+2x) etc.

Comment: @analog_designer, you cannot perform [_factorization_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization) without knowing the roots (solutions) of your equation, which (as I stated above) you cannot calculate as your polynomials is degree five. If you give us more context and details (e.g. where did you get this problem, what do you actually want to calculate, do these coefficients [$k, L, R$] have any relationship or known values ...), we might help you with some other ideas.

Comment: `Factor` is the command that factorizes polynomials. But your polynomial cannot be factorized.

Comment: @Domen This equation belongs to a denominator of the Transfer function and I need to find poles of the transfer function to determine stability of system. It is related to electronic filters.

Comment: The answer you have (all the things like s->Root[ ]) are the roots of the equation. If you plug in numbers for the variables, you will get numerical values.

Comment: @bill I want to get roots with L, R and k.

Comment: "I want to get roots with L, R and k" -- not going to happen. One thing you might try is to look at RootLocusPlot, which will allow you to see what happens as any one of the parameters changes (while the others are fixed). See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootLocusPlot.html

Comment: For example: poly[L_, R_, k_] := 
 1 + L/R s + 4 k L s^2 + (3 k L^2 s^3)/R + 
  2 k^2 L^2 s^4 + (k^2 L^3 s^5)/R; RootLocusPlot[k Ratios[CoefficientList[poly[2, 1, k], k]], {k, 0, 3}]   This shows how the roots change with L=2, R=1 as k is varied between 0 and 3. You can see that these particular values are stable for all the k.